# Why do you have to unmount a drive before formatting or resizing it?

Tags: automounting, unmounting

I always have to unmount a filesystem/drive (like a USB) before formatting it or resizing it. Why is this necessary?

On a related note (I feel like this would help me understand why it is necessary) what exactly happens when a filesystem/drive is mounted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, once mounted the device is assumed by the system to be of a fixed size and fixed format. Being able to resize or reformat a device in an hot-plugged manner would require the operating system to probe all the devices frequently, which would be extremely inefficient.

And, about your second question, when a device is mounted, the device is accessible through a driver from the operating system. The users may access it through the mounting point located somewhere in the file-system (in fact a file-system is just an easy way to give the control of the mass-storage devices to the users).

I might have miss the point of your question, but you should maybe try to be a bit more specific when you ask question. I would advice you to read this famous text from ESR: [How to Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Comment: no, you answered my question perfectly. thank you!! and thanks for the link, as well.

Comment: Note that some filesystems support online resizing (e.g., ext4 can be grown bigger while mounted, see https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/ext4grow.html).

Comment: The operating system will also assume the contents (files) don't change